# Applying a function to column of table

Tags: tables

I got Bruno's solution to work but now *xcolor* bizarrely gives me 'TeX capacity exceeded' when I use  `\rowcolors`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltablex,colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\keepXColumns
\makeatletter
\def\KWP@safe@newline{%
  \iffalse{\fi
  \let\KWP@old@newline\\%
  \let\\\cr
  \iffalse}\fi
}
\def\KWP@restore@newline{\iffalse{\fi\let\\\KWP@old@newline\iffalse}\fi}

\newcolumntype{\arg}[1]{%
  >{\KWP@safe@newline
    #1{\ignorespaces \@sharp\unskip}%
    \KWP@restore@newline
    \span\@gobbletwo}%
  m{3cm}%
}
\newcolumntype{\argmulti}[1]{%
  >{\KWP@safe@newline
    #1{\ignorespaces \@sharp\unskip}%
    \KWP@restore@newline
    \@gobbletwo}%
  c%
}
\makeatother
% A simple test function:
\newcommand{\macro}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\arrayrulecolor{orange}
\rowcolors[\hline]{1}{yellow!25}{gray!25}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|\arg{\macro}|m{2.5cm}|X|}
%\noalign{\hrule}
\hline
  aaa & bbb & AAA \\\hline
  fff & ggg & FFF\\\hline
  hhh & \multicolumn{2}{|\argmulti{\macro}|}{HHH}\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

The 'capacity exceeded' problem seems to have come from *tabularx*. *tabular* compiles without trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't described what you are trying to achieve, nor why the code in the other question is not good for your purposes. I'm assuming that the question is "Why doesn't the code compile?"

- There is no `\documentclass` in your code snippet, not `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`;
- `\textcolor` requires a package (for instance `\usepackage{color}`, but it has probably been superseeded by other packages);
- when defining macros with `@` in their names, they need to be placed between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`;
- you omitted two definitions, `\KWP@safe@newline` and `\KWP@restore@newline`;
- and `\ang` should be `\arg` in the preamble of the tabular.

With these changes,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{color}
\keepXColumns
\makeatletter
\def\KWP@safe@newline{%
  \iffalse{\fi
  \let\KWP@old@newline\\%
  \let\\\cr
  \iffalse}\fi
}
\def\KWP@restore@newline{\iffalse{\fi\let\\\KWP@old@newline\iffalse}\fi}

\newcolumntype{\arg}[1]{%
  >{\KWP@safe@newline
    #1{\ignorespaces \@sharp\unskip}%
    \KWP@restore@newline
    \span\@gobbletwo}%
  m{3cm}%
}
\newcolumntype{\argmulti}[1]{%
  >{\KWP@safe@newline
    #1{\ignorespaces \@sharp\unskip}%
    \KWP@restore@newline
    \@gobbletwo}%
  c%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\macro}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\hsize.5\hsize\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|\arg{\macro}|m{2.5cm}|X|}
  aaa & bbb & AAA \\
  fff & ggg & FFF\\ 
  % hhh & \multicolumn{2}{|\argmulti{\macro}|}{HHH}\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

On a side note, getting the whole column to be red can be done with `>{\color{red}}c` in the preamble.

Comment: @Bruno: I assumed you were familiar with all the needed prelims. That was why I didn't include them. Anyway, did it actually compile on your system? I keep getting _Illegal pream-token ( ): `c' used._

Comment: @Ahmed: this doesn't perclude writing a minimal working example and describing what you want to achieve. --- I just copied and pasted the code above in a fresh file, compiled with `pdflatex`. Can you give the result of `\listfiles`?

Comment: Since the \enddocument is not reached, I had to call `\@dofilelist` instead.

File List: article.cls, size10.clo, trace.sty, ltablex.sty, longtable.sty, tabularx.sty, array.sty, color.sty, color.cfg, dvips.def

Comment: @Ahmed. What really matters in the file list is the version of each file. Perhaps try to replace the `X` column by `c`, `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}` by `\begin{tabular}`, and `\end{tabularx}` by `\end{tabular}`, also removing `\keepXColumns`? You can then replace `ltablex.sty` by `array.sty`, and see what happens. If it still breaks, try replacing the `\arg{\macro}` column by a `c` column. etc. Get to a minimal broken example, and post it. We probably have slightly different version of a package.

Comment: @Bruno: I am yet to change the document, but here is the full file list: article.cls (2007/10/19 v1.4h), size10.clo (2007/10/19 v1.4h), trace.sty (2003/04/30 v1.1c), ltablex.sty ( 1995/11/06 v1.0), longtable.sty (2004/02/01 v4.11), tabularx.sty (1999/01/07 v2.07), array.sty (2008/09/09 v2.4c), xcolor.sty (2007/01/21 v2.11), color.cfg (2007/01/18 v1.5), dvips.def (1999/02/16 v3.0i).

Comment: @Ahmed: Thank you for the list: the versions are identical. Have you copied and pasted the exact code I gave? `trace.sty` is not loaded in my case. Also check that sometimes spurious spaces may appear when copying and pasting?

Comment: @Bruno: I will check it again. In the meantime, _collcell_ offers an alternative that works with _tabularx_ and _ltablex_: `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell\macro}c<{\endcollectcell}}`.

Comment: @Ahmed: indeed, you're right, and it is another answer to the same question you link to. In the case of coloring, you can simply use `>{\color{red}}c`. Same idea for changing font `>{\itshape}c`, etc.